# Packaging and distributing Projects pypi

Tags: python, pypi

i am following [this](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/) tutorial. it explains the topic with help of [sampleproject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject). The **init**.py looks like this.

```
def main():
    """Entry point for the application script"""
    print("Call your main application code here")
```

what does "call your main application code here" ?should i write my "from test_class import test" and create test_class.py file in the same directory?

Comment: It is just a print statement. You need to write the main here.

Comment: @kvivek if class i want to publish is in test_class.py file( in same directory), what should i write

Answer (score 1):

`def main()` is just an ordinary function. You need to call the main. May be in `if __name__ == "__main__":` block or call it explicitly like `main()`. There is no rule than for import statement, Preferably all the import statements are written in the beginning for the global scope. If you write the targeted import statement like `from test_class import test` inside the `def main()`, then test module or class will have a limited scope of `main()`.